# SSRS matrix custom code

Tags: sql, matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to produce a matrix report that could look like the following:

```
        July     August    September
Stock   5000(a)  =a+b-c
Pos     3000(b)
Sales   3500(c)
```

What i need to do is roll over the sum into the next column stock figure. I have attempted to create some custom code in order to do this

```
  Dim runningStockFigure as Integer =5000


Public Function returnStock as Integer
    return runningStockFigure 
End Function

Public Function addToRunningStock(ByVal input as Integer, ByVal type1 as Integer) as Integer    

    dim a as Integer =0
    a=input*type1
    runningStockFigure=runningStockFigure +a
    return runningStockFigure
End Function
```

What I've then tried to do is

```
          July                                        August              
Stock   =code.returnStock                      =code.returnStock
POs     =code.addToRunningStock(3000,1)
Sales   =code.addToRunningStock(3500,-1)
```

(Sorry if the example is a little crude)

Although the code doesn't seem to work. I don't know if its the way the matrix grid processes the code and what order it does it in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand this is quite a niche question, however I shall provide updates as and when I have them.  I believe the matrix processes custom code left to right. I will test this and provide code after

Comment: Ok the only way I could do it was to make separate custom for each row. As it turns out custom code runs on a row by row basis .

Comment: Do your custom functions always return 5000? I think the issue is your define the variable outside of functions. Since you give value for this global variable, it will always return this value. I suggest you define a variable within custom functions to return it out.